# Tem como abrir arquivos "accdb" access com PHP usando PDO no linux?

Tags: php, microsoft-access

Isso mesmo pessoal, procurei mas não achei como abrir arquivos accdb usando PDO no PHP, meu ambiente é linux.

Comment: Dei uma Googlada rápida e encontrei esse artigo. https://www.sitepoint.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/

Comment: Rapaz vai me ajudar muito, procurei mas as dicas eram só com ADODB, outra suite do php, como procurei paginas em portugues não vi essa aí, bora fazer testes, tanks